# How to find all answers to $g'(t)+2g(t)=8$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing a quiz on differential equations and I'm having trouble with one of the questions. The question goes like this(translated):

Enter the option(s) that satisfy that
$g(t)$
is a solution to the differential equation
$g'(t)+2g(t)=8$
A: $g(t)=e^{-2t}$
B: $g(t)=4+e^{2t}$
C: $g(t)=4$
D: $g(t)=4e^{t}$
E: $g(t)=4-3e^{-2t}$
I used the integration factor method to solve this:
Multiply every term with: $e^{2t}$
$g' \cdot e^{2t}+2g \cdot e^{2t}=8e^{2t}$
$\frac{d}{dt}(g \cdot e^{2t})=8e^{2t}$
$\int(\frac{d}{dt}(g \cdot e^{2t}))dt=\int(8e^{2t})dt$
$g \cdot e^{2t}=\int(8e^{2t})dt$
$g \cdot e^{2t}=4 \cdot e^{2t} + C$
$g=4 + \frac{C}{e^{2t}}$
$g=4 + C \cdot e^{-2t}$
So anwer C is correct($C=0$) and anwer E is correct($C=-3$). This also makes sense if we try with those solutions in the original differential equation:
Option C:
$g(t)=4$
$g'(t)=0$
$(0)+2(4)=8$
$8=8$

Option E:
$g(t)=4-3e^{-2t}$
$g'(t)=6e^{-2t}$
$(6e^{-2t})+2(4-3e^{-2t})=8$
$6e^{-2t}+8-6e^{-2t}=8$
$8=8$
According to the quiz answers, this was indeed valid solutions, however option A ($g(t)=e^{-2t}$) was also a valid solution. I have no idea why. I would really appreciate an explanation of that, thanks.

Comment: Option A is not a valid solution. Without initial conditions you cannot determine the value of $C$ so any value of $C$ is valid